# How do I prove the following that $DA^{-1}(x)=A^{-1}$ where $A$ is a linear operator and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> How do I prove the following that $DA^{-1}(x)=A^{-1}$ where $A$ is a linear operator and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I am doing the proof of the inverse function theorem and it uses the fact that $DA^{-1}(x)=A^{-1}$ but I am not sure how to show this. [Here $D$ denotes the differentiation operator]

More precisely the statement goes like this:

Let $\lambda$ be the linear transformation $Df(a)$. Then $\lambda$ is non-singular, since det $f'(a)\neq 0$. Now $D(\lambda^{-1}\circ f)(a) = D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))\circ Df(a) = \lambda^{-1}\circ Df(a)$ is the identity linear transformation.

I don't understand what does differentiating a linear operator even mean?

Comment: I can suggest to recheck the definition of $D$ and write out how it acts on linear maps $x \mapsto Ax$ writing out the domains and codomains. Trying it out with $A$ being $1\times 1$ or $2\times 2$ might help as well. Roughly speaking $Df$ at the point $x$ is the linear approximation to $f$ at $x$. And for the $f$ here the prescription for $f$ and $Df$ happen to coincide because of the nature of $f$. This is what helped me realize what is going on, hope there is a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the confusing part of this question is the fact that the derivative in this context is the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). The total derivative of a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ at a point $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is the unique linear map $Df_x:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ ($Df(x)$ in the notation of your question) such that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(x + h) - f(x) - Df_x(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.
$$
I find that a helpful step in making this intuitive is considering the single-variable ($m = n = 1$) case. Consider the *linear* function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = ax$. Under the usual perspective on the derivative, the derivative of $f$ at any point $x \in \Bbb R$ is the *number* $a$. Under the *total derivative* perspective, the derivative of $f$ at any point $x \in \Bbb R$ is the *linear transformation* $Df_x(h) = ah$.
in other words, $Df_x = f$.

One point that bothered me as a student was this: doesn't this version of the derivative contradict the usual notion that the derivative of a linear function is "constant"? I would argue it doesn't: the fact that the "derivative of $f$" is constant is reflected in the fact that $Df_x(h)$ does not depend on $x$. If we consider the function $g(x) = x^2$ for the sake of contrast, we find that the total derivative of $g$ is given by $Dg_x(h) = 2xh$, corresponding to the (non-constant) "usual" derivative of $2x$.

If $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, we likewise have two perspectives on the derivative. The perspective corresponding to the "usual" approach is that the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $J_x$. The total-derivative perspective is that the derivative of $f$ is the linear map $Df_x(h) = J_x h$. If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is the linear transformation $f(x) = Mx$ for some matrix $M$, then from the first perspective we would say that the derivative of $f$ at all points is the Jacobian matrix $J_x = M$. From the total derivative perspective, the derivative is $Df_x(h) = Mh$. Again, we find that $Df_x = f$.